# Robot Framework Python Remote Server with credentials

Tags: python, robotframework, remote-server

We are investigating the methods of the [Robot Framework Python Remote Server](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer/blob/master/README.rst#supported-library-apis) in order to run tests libraries on other machines. We were already able to make the Robot Framework run. I was now wondering if it is possible to demand credentials, username/password combination, to ensure that only allowed persons are able to remotely run tests on the remote machine.

I already looked through the documentation, but I wasn't able to find such a feature.